# Monte Carlo simulation: how to make it computationally less expensive?

Tags: matlab, montecarlo

*Objective*

The objective is to compute the price of exotic options under Merton's jump-diffusion model through Monte-Carlo simulation. Now, before I do that, I want to test the accuracy of the Monte-Carlo technique by simulating the price of a European call option with strike `K` and maturity `T`.

*Method and problem*

I have to simulate possible scenario, i.e possible stock price paths under Merton's model. Therefore, I construct a time grid of length `N` with step size `ht`. The objective is then to compute `S(1),...,S(N)`, i.e the stock price on the time grid. This is what happens in the inner loop. Now this inner loop is just for **one** path. I have to do it for `P = 10^5` paths (outer loop).

*Problem*

Using the loops, this is very time consuming and unpractical. Therefore, I would like to rewrite the code with a minimal use of loops. However, I do not know how? Essentially since I do not know how to generate the compound Poisson random variables without a loop.

```
function [Call] = ExoticPricingMerton(S0,K,mu,delta,lambda,sigma,r,q,Maturity)

% This script computes the price of a European option through Monte-Carlo simulation

% mu = -0.12, r = 0.033, q = 0.0022, delta = 0.14, sigma = 0.34, 
% Maturity = 1.12, S_0 = 100, K = 95. 
% r is the risk free rate
% T is the maturity of the option
% {mu,delta,lambda,sigma} are the Merton model parameters
% S_0 is the spot price
% K is the strike of the option

ht = 1/252; %trading days
P = 10^5; %Number of simulations
Tgrid = (0:ht:Maturity); 
N = length(Tgrid);

omega = r-q-((1/2)*sigma^2+lambda*(exp(mu+(1/2)*delta^2)-1)); 

S = zeros(P,N);
S(:,1) = S0; 

for i=1:P
    for j=2:length(Tgrid)
        N = poissrnd(lambda*ht);
        J = cumsum([0, normrnd(mu,delta,1,N)]); 
        Z = normrnd(0,1);
        S(i,j) = S(i,j-1)*exp(omega*ht + sigma*sqrt(ht)*Z + J(end));
    end 
end 


% European Call option
A = max(S(:,end)-K,0); 
Call = exp(-r*Maturity)*(1/P)*sum(A);
```

*Output* 
price of a European call option with strike `K` and maturity `T`. `S` is a matrix where each row is a sample path and the amount of columns is the amount of simulation (`P`).

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? and also, avoid using `grid`, it's a reserved word in MATLAB.

Comment: I have updated the code. I hope this is more clear. I also changed grid to timegrid as you suggested.

Comment: Good, but you are still using `grid` in `N = length(grid);`, and there are many variables here which I don't have a clue how the look like. Try to make our example runnable, with some small sample or arbitrary data.

Comment: Sorry again, I have tried to be as complete as possible now.

Comment: We still need some parameter values in order to call the function.

Comment: I have included some parameter values.

Comment: What is `lambda`? Please edit the post to include a line calling `ExoticPricingMerton` with the parameters.

Comment: You may have some mistake in your code. First you define: `N = length(Tgrid);` and then you write `N = poissrnd(lambda*ht);`, which doesn't make sense because you use `N` as a size in `J = cumsum([0, normrnd(mu,delta,1,N)]);`. What did you mean?

Comment: could it be that you look for `J = cumsum([0, poissrnd(lambda*ht,1,N)])`,  where `N = length(Tgrid)`, instead of the `J` you wrote?

Comment: is this question still on?

Comment: @Finn the OP doesn't seem to respond anymore...